# comparing a password to a hash queried from database?

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I send a password to php to get compared to the hash stored in the database.

my php is:

```
$enteredUser = $_POST["username"];
$enteredPass = $_POST["password"];
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT passhash FROM user WHERE `username` = '$enteredUser'");
$passHash = mysql_result($query, 0);
if(password_verify($enteredPass, $passHash)){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failure";
}
```

I also tried using `mysqli_fetch_array()` as well, but it still doesn't work. Does anyone know why this isn't working? thanks in advance to anyone who can help. (on a side note, `$passHash` returns null)

Comment: Change `$passHash = mysql_result($query, 0);` to `$passHash = mysqli_result($query, 0);` see how that goes. It should make 'er kick into 1st gear ;-)

Comment: mysqli_result() doesn't exist and yes i did try it, it just doesn't run the success function from ajax. I apologize it does exist, but that doesn't change the fact that it still doesn't work.

Comment: Did you fetch the result by `mysqli_fetch_array` for example? What does `password_verify` do?

Comment: You are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing two extensions, mysqli and mysql - `mysqli_query` and then `mysql_result`.

You are also open to SQL injection and should be sanitising your POST input before passing it directly to MySQL.

`mysqli_query` returns a result object and you then need to fetch the results from that object.

`mysqli_fetch_row` will return one row.

```
$enteredUser = $_POST["username"];
$enteredPass = $_POST["password"];
//...
$resultset = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT passhash FROM user WHERE `username` = '$enteredUser'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_row($resultset);
if(password_verify($enteredPass,$result[0])){
    echo "success";
}else{
    echo "failure";
}
```

Comment: no offense, but I'm not stupid, I'm just showing parts of my code here, I already have taken precautions and this doesn't answer my question at all, I tried using one and then the other, not both. I only use mysqli because mysql is depreciated, and if i am to use mysql_result() i would find another way that wasn't depreciated.

Comment: What do you call this => `mysql_result` @Ozay34 I posted a comment to that effect also. Before this answer was given. Had it not been the case, then tell me and I'd of came up with another idea. Now it's up to the person who gave you the answer to figure it out.

Comment: I never said you were stupid. You are using both in the code you have posted. Read it again maybe?

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I'm going crazy, it does exist, but it still stops the function from running. Edit: according to [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) it doesn't seem to act the same way, maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
$enteredUser = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["username"]);
$enteredPass = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["password"]);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `username` = '$enteredUser'";
$result = $con->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows === 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    if (password_verify($enteredPass, $row['passhash'])) 
    {
    echo "Success";
    }
    else {
    echo "Sorry";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did solve my own problem with a simple while loop, i guess it will work fine, thanks everyone for your input:

```
$passHash = ''; 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $passHash .= $row["passhash"]; 
}
```

Comment: Great news. I posted an answer for you to try also. But hey, if it works, all the better! Do try mine and see though, just so I know. Cheers

Comment: yes it does, and i think, just because it is less code i will keep it, thanks for putting up with all my shenanigans :)

Comment: The shorter the better; and don't worry about it. I didn't think they were shenanigans. Password stuff can be a pain in the neck at times; don't I know it. I once spent 2 days on a hashing function ;-) Cheers - Btw, did you try mine? I think you said you did.

Comment: oh i tried JBES's i got confused by the name, but thanks everyone!